# Change data type to People or Group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, import

I have done a excel import and all the columns are successfully imported. One of the field is **Assigned to** whose data type is *Single Line of Text*.

Is there a way to change the data type of this field to **People or group** after the excel import (i.e after the field has already been created).

I saw some posts saying that it is not possible in SharePoint 2007. Just in case if it is available in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: I think the easiest is to create a new People/Group field then open the list in DataSheet view and copy/paste the column. You have to manually delete every single entry that have no matching account

Answer (score 4):

No it is still not available. You will need to create a new column as a person/group field and then in Quick Edit view, copy over the data. Then delete your single line of text column.

Answer (score 1):

you can run a PowerShell or have your admin run it (like I did) to update an empty person or group column you create. This is worth it with large lists. Just update the column names to match your list.

```
 #Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$url = "http://SiteName"
$listName = "ListName"

$Source1ColumnName = "Modified By1"
$Dest1ColumnName = "ModBy"
$Source2ColumnName = "Delegate To"
$Dest2ColumnName = "DelegatedTo"

# Get Current Date Time
function Get-TimeStamp {
    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
}

# Get Site Collection Details
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
# Get List Details
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

# Temporary allow Unsafe updates 
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

# Output Current Date Time
Write-Host "Started - $(Get-TimeStamp)"

# Loop through each item in list and set column data
foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
    try {
        $SourceValue = $item[$Source1ColumnName]
        $SourceValue2 = $item[$Source2ColumnName]

        If ($SourceValue) {
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser = $Web.EnsureUser($SourceValue)
            $item[$Dest1ColumnName] = $spuser
        }
        If ($SourceValue2) { 
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser2 = $Web.EnsureUser($SourceValue2)
            $item[$Dest2ColumnName] = $spuser2 
        }
        $item.Update()
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}
# Output Current Date Time
Write-Host "Ended - $(Get-TimeStamp)"

# Reset Unsafe updates 
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false
```